# My flutter project was working fine but now it's showing error while running it

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My Flutter project was working perfectly fine. I had implemented google map and  I wanted to draw routes between source and destination points on flutter google map. The map was showing too.

But now when I am running my code I am getting error. Please help me solving this. I can't even run my project now.

**The error I am getting:**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':hexcolor'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

my **pubspec.yaml**:

```
name: thehelpdesk
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  introduction_screen: ^1.0.7
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  hexcolor: ^1.0.6
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.4
  email_validator: '^1.0.5'
  validate: ^1.7.0
  dio: 3.0.10
  pin_code_fields: ^5.0.1
  geolocator: ^6.1.14
  google_maps_flutter: 0.5.21+17
  google_map_polyline:
  permission: ^0.1.7
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.3



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  sqflite: ^1.3.2+2
  path_provider: ^1.6.24

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/sp_screen.png
    - assets/images/reg_logo.png
    - assets/images/email@_icon.png
    - assets/images/mobile_icon.png
    - assets/images/arrow_icon.png
    - assets/images/Invoice.png
    - assets/images/cake.png
    - assets/images/calender.png
    - assets/images/Reminder.png
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Poppins
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf

    - family: Roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf

  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Well.. It seems to be the package `HexColor` that's causing your problem. For the specific problem I'd need more info.

Comment: @Stijn2210 I have tried already removing the HexColor package but still getting the same error. Let me know what kind of information you want

Comment: Did you `flutter clean` after removing the package?

Comment: @William , yes I did